# Webservice Reference file won't update

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap

Alright, I'm mostly posting because I'm going to tear out my hair and need a break, but maybe someone can point me in the right direction with this.

I'm working on some existing software that uses a webservices through VB.NET to connect up to a SQL Database. My issue is that my WebService file isn't updating the actual Webservice. For example, I'll have the file MyWS.asmx, and MyWS.asmx.vb, and in the vb I have something like...

```
'bunch of webservice calls

<WebMethod()> _    
Public Function PreExistingFunction(ByVal something As someObject)
    Return something
End Function

'more webservice calls
```

And this used to work just fine. But then, I needed to add a secondary ByVal to it, so I changed it to this...

```
'bunch of webservice calls

<WebMethod()> _    
Public Function PreExistingFunction(ByVal something As someObject, ByVal somethingElse As someObject)
    Return somethingElse
End Function

'more webservice calls
```

I then go through, kill my existing webservices, and debug my WS project. However, the localhost that pulls up doesn't include the new 'somethingelse' byval. I originally thought it must be pulling from somewhere else, so I decided to do some testing, and I was able to COMPLETELY remove MyWS.asmx.vb's code, then when I ran the debug for the WS project, it STILL shows all of the original functions.

It's gotta be pulling from a different file, but I haven't created any other ones, and the only place it takes a filepath is in MyWS.asmx, and that gives this line of code...

```
<%@ webservice language="VB" codebehind="~\MyWS.asmx.vb" class="MyWS.MyWS" %>
```

Again, everything worked completely fine until I added the secondary function. I've tried adding different subs/functions/calls, removing others, and nothing works.

Surprisingly, rolling my MyWS project back to an earlier version actually DID get rid of all of my recent changes, (I had added the PreExistingFunction a few weeks ago, rolled back to prior to this function), and now it won't let me add the PreExistingFunction back in...

Any ideas or tips for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

Web References are not like DLL references, that are not automatically updated.

You need to right-click on the service reference in your solution explorer and choose the option to "Update Service Reference".

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned - I've done that, but prior to getting to that step the webservice pops up into a new web browser, and you're able to navigate the .asmx file to see what functions are being included in the webservice. So I'm just checking prior to actually updating the webservice.